# Equation on $\mathbb{R}$ : $(x+y+z)^3=x^3+y^3+z^3$

Tags: real-numbers, symmetric-polynomials

How would i find **all** the $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}$ verifying $(x+y+z)^3=x^3+y^3+z^3$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation

$$(x+y+z)^3 - x^3 - y^3 - z^3 = 0$$

as

$$(x+y)(y+z)(x+z) =0$$

Making the solution identically those values such that at least one of the equations
$$
x=-y\\
y=-z\\
z=-x
$$
holds.

Comment: Great comment Sam. You are really cool.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal That's nice.

Comment: You bet it is ;)